# EJB pool overflow

Tags: java, jakarta-ee, ejb

Stateless EJB objects are pooled. When two clients use the same bean at the same time then two objects the pool are created, one for each client. If client trying to use bean, but the maximum permissible number of beans in the pool has already been reached and the none of the BUSY beans become available then client request is not services.
But but what exactly will be behavior in this situation? Some exception will be thrown or something else?

Answer (score 0):

I already found the answer:

> If all instances of an EJB class are active and `max-beans-in-free-pool`
>   has been reached, new clients requesting the EJB class will be blocked
>   until an active EJB completes a method call. If the transaction times
>   out (or, for non-transactional calls, if five minutes elapse),
>   WebLogic Server throws a `RemoteException` for a remote client or an
>   `EJBException` for a local client.